# Model containing a list of its own model type (Recursive Modeling?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependencies

Okay, this may be trivial, but I'm hoping somebody can give me a straightforward answer. Let's say you have two Models in an MVC project, and one model contains a list of the other model. The two models would look something like this:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Wheel> Wheels { get; set; }
}

public class Wheel
{
    [Key]
    public int WheelId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int VehicleId { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public virtual Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say you have this same thing, but with only one model. At first thought, I thought it would look something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    public int MyClassId { get; set; }

    public string MyData { get; set; }

    public virtual List<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
}
```

This throws me off only because `MyClasses` is specified as a navigation property. Which would mean that each `MyClasses[i]` would have to have a `MyClass` property and another `MyclassId` that both reference the parent `MyClass`. After thinking about this for a while, I started to get dizzy. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Exactly what I posted. The only addition I guess would be to say that  `MyClass`'s data is determined by combining the data for each object in `MyClasses`.

Comment: Google `self-referencing model entity framework` I saw plenty of examples using `code first` and you can probably use that to figure it out with attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct approach to generate a proper SQL database:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    public int MyClassId { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }

    public virtual Classes Classes { get; set; }
}

public class Classes
{
    [Key]
    public int ClassesId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int MyClassId { get; set; }

    public List<MyClass> Classes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual MyClass MyClass { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with your `MyClass` instance:

```
public class Class
{
  [Key]
  public int ClassId { get; set; }
  public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class Classes
{
  public virtual List<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}
```

In your view `@model .ViewModels.Classes. Doesn't get any easier and don't make yourself dizzier than you suppose to be.

In short, don't do circular referencing, break the circle by naming one class differently, so your model in the view will know what to look for and what to work with. You **can** work with circles of course. Problem is that its a nightmare to maintain. Do yourself a favor and make your life easier.

**Update**

```
public class MyClasses
{
  public List<Classes> OtherClasses;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need each `Class` to have a reference to a list of other Classes. Unless I'm overlooking something, I don't think this is what I need.

Comment: If I understood you correctly (not sure I did), look at the update.
As long as you fine with naming of those classes that referencing other classes, try to avoid any circles. If you can't - you can't, will have to live with it and maintain it (issues with EF), but try avoiding, as having them is hard to maintain for one, and expect unexpected and difficult bugs in the future. Especially if someone else takes over the code.